# How can i insert a white dot when pressing keycode 9 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm trying to insert a white dot and some spaces when I press the keycode 9(TAB), but i can't get it to work. When I insert the dot it never appears in white, it's allways black.

Can someone help me?

The code that im using is this one:

```
function WebHtmlEditor1_KeyDown(oEditor, keyCode, oEvent) {

      if (keyCode == 9) {
         var point = document.createElement("SPAN");
         var object = document.createElement("SPAN");

         var style = point.style;
         style.fontColor = "White";
         console.log(style);

         point.innerHTML = '<span style:"color="#ffffff"">TESTE</span>';
         object.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

         //console.log(object);
         iged_insText(point.innerText, false);
         iged_insText(object.innerText, false);
         oEvent.cancel = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: A JSFiddle would help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have **many** typos.

```
point.innerHTML = '<span style:"color="#ffffff"">TESTE</span>';
```

1. A colon (`:`) after the `style` attribute when you
   should have an equals (`=`).
2. An equals (`=`) after the `color` declaration when you
   should have a colon(`:`).
3. Double-quotes around the CSS declaration.

Replace that line with this one:

```
point.innerHTML = '<span style="color:#ffffff">TESTE</span>';
```

Comment: @user3780994 Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or provide the whole code because we cannot test this way.

Comment: @user3780994 Check my answer again.

Comment: i'm using infragistics webhltmeditor, and text that i edit in it is to use in a report (.rdl). But the TAB isnt recognized in the report. So i trade the TAB for white spaces, but the report, at the start of the line doesnt recognize them either. So i thought to add a white dot and the spaces, but i can not get the white dot to appear. It only appears in black.

Comment: I hope i maid myself clear cause my english is not the best in the world xD.

Comment: I cannot provide the all code because this application its not mine, its from the company and i can get fired xD

Comment: nope, that way doesn't work again. Its the same the text "TESTE" appears in black.

Comment: @user3780994 Sorry, you provided us with a single function and I fixed the only obvious problem with it. I cannot test without having more code so I cannot help further :/

Comment: It could be other stylesheets overriding the colour - what do you see if you inspect the element in Chrome's /  Firefox's debugger?